# Finding loud events in lengthy ambient recording?

Tags: audio-recording

I just made a recording of ambient sound over night. Now, I want to find loud events made by animals, humans, etc. Loud means: Louder than the background noise, in this case mostly caused by waves at the shore.

*What technique can be used?*

Of course, I already looked at the wave form in Sound Forge Audio Studio. However, more comfortable would be a software that finds the loud parts for me, or somehow highlights them.

Comment: While not directly applicable, some answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/q/545329/141595) might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Software with a spectrogram would be my choice because the sounds would probably be more noticable at a glance.

e.g. Izotope RX (it has useful options to customise the spectrogram rendering parameters)

Otherwise you could use a 'detect silence' funtion which most DAWs have, they can split the audio when they detect the signal level going above a threshold which you could set just above the background noise level.

Answer (score 2):

If you have protools - strip silcene can accomplish this.

just start with the threshold all the way up and then turn it down until just the parts that are loud enough to cross the threshold are highlighted.